# Error: "Failed to create symbolic link: operation not permited" as root

Tags: bash, ubuntu

**System informations (test environment)**:

- ***OS***: Ubuntu
- ***OS Versions (codenames)***: *trusty* and above (upgraded)

**Problem description**:

**Notes**:

1. All bellow steps and tasks were done as **root**
2. Using "[" and "]" as delimeters of placeholder

I had created on a clean USB stick a fat partition and had mounted it with write permissions, before copying files on it. To reduce the number of duplicated files, I wanted to create symbolic links for some, but in the result, I saw following error message:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '[filename]': Operation not permited
```

This had suprised me, since root has unlimited access to most of the filesystem (there is an exception for some system folders, where permissions to some foldes and files are restricted).

Any ideas to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Please provide some details: 1) what commands have you used to do the thing? 2) from where have you tried to copy files? 3) what are the files you want to create symlinks for? Thanks.

Comment: 1) I was trying to use a basic for loop and ln. In the code, I will use placeholders sorrounded in betweem "<" and ">": ```for a in <dir_from>/*: do ln -svf $a <dir_to>; done ```

Comment: 2) the target dir was a sub-folder of the source dir

Comment: 3) that is't as much important, but they weren't special files that could be protected